# Excel Formula If a value matches a value in a range of cells then return corresponding value in a different cell

Tags: excel, compare, formula

I am trying to get excel to take a job code from sheet 1

[image: Sheet 1 Fields]

Compare it to a list of job codes & their respective salary grades on sheet 2

[image: Sheet 2 Fields]

And if the job codes match, take that respective salary grade value (from sheet 2) and put it in column B (Salary Grade) of Sheet 1

I've tried a few different IF formulas and just can't get it to work out!

Really appreciate any help out there, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in B2 and copy down:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: I was able to get it to work now with your assistance! I just had the columns switched on my 2nd sheet which was giving errors. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @DRandles please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.